# Tableau - display total and % of total in two columns in table view

Tags: tableau-api

I have one measure: Reghrs.

I want to display the 'total' and the '% of total' side by side in a table (in two columns). Currently tableau only gives me the view of two rows. What do I need to do? Please help.

Thanks.
[Current Tableau View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dbT4.png)

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

Drag the SUM(RegHrs) & SUM(RegHrs) table calc pills to the rows shelf, and convert them to "Discrete". This will place the info into the crosstab style that you would like.